# when can i apply for visiting to UK after deportation

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, family, removal, deportation

i was deported from uk in march 2015 on the basis of overstayer which occur after my ex wife age is not up to 21yrs by the time of marriage due to changing of marriageable age from 18-21yrs which my solicitor didn't informed us by then until my application was refused though they gave us a right of appeal but my solicitor kept it from us for a year until we decided to withdraw our file from him.
we send for reconciliation which nothing happened for 4yrs till 2014 when i was served with a letter of liable to deportation/ detention without any criminal record atall.
I have a daughter for a person settled in uk but not british yet and the child did not have a passport yet which i mentioned during the proceeding and obtain a court order under a family law that i'm the father of the child though she was in a relationship with an european citizen by the time of birth of the child which they are officially divorced now and i have a sister that has a british pp and children which i stayed with when i'm in uk which followed me to the proceeding during my hearing in court under appeal. pls when can i apply to see my daughter and is it best to apply to see my daughter or my family. please advice me on what to do and when can i apply to see my daughter not to stay but to see her maybe just for a week.

Comment: This situation is sufficiently serious that **you should do _nothing_ on your own** without the advice of [an immigration lawyer](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/search-directory.php).

Comment: If you will allow a bit of pedantry, you were not deported, you were 'removed'; there is nothing to gain by criminalizing yourself.